# read.sql_query works, read sql_table doesn't

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

Trying to import a table from a SQLite into Pandas DF:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

cnxn = sqlite3.Connection("my_db.db")
c = cnxn.cursor()
```

Using this command works: `pd.read_sql_query('select * from table1', con=cnxn)`. This doesn't : `df = pd.read_sql_table('table1', con=cnxn)`.

Response :

> `ValueError: Table table1 not found`

What could be the issue?

Comment: Read the documentation. You can't use a `SQLIte` connection as the `con` argument. **SQLite DBAPI connection mode not supported.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQLite in Python the `pd.read_sql_table()` is not possible. Info found in Pandas doc.

Hence it's considered to be a DB-API when running the commands thru Python.

[pd.read_sql_table() Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_table.html)

> Given a table name and a SQLAlchemy connectable, returns a DataFrame.
> This function **does not support DBAPI** connections.