# Reading SQL-table by pandas-python

Tags: python, pandas, database, sqlite, connection

Could somebody help with pandas. I can't read sqlite3 table.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sq

with sq.connect("master.db") as con:
    table = "personal"
    df = pd.read_sql_table(table, con)
```

Db file and code are in same directory. Python rise NotImplementedError

Comment: Yes, your answer help me, thanks you very much! I only little modified it

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73792402/5320906)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read the content of your table you can simply use:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sq

with sq.connect("master.db") as con:
   params = ["personal"]    
   df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM ?", con, params = params)
```

As stated in the comments, the usage of params in the query is recommended to block sql-injections

Comment: Your solution is prone to SQL injection attacks. Use `params` instead of concatenating directly to the query.

Comment: ok i made an edit

Answer (score 1):

## hope this will help and give you a solution.

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("master.db")

curr = conn.cursor()

for row in curr.execute("SELECT * FROM personal")
    print(row)

conn.close()
```

Comment: highlight the code pls :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).